# Change sticky navigation bar color scheme based on content below in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, nav

How do I achieve a sticky navigation bar that changes its color scheme based on the content being served below it in React? I've seen solutions to this written in jQuery but no idea on how to implement such thing in React. The apple newsroom website has a great example: [apple.com/newsroom](https://www.apple.com/newsroom)
[GIF](https://thumbs.gfycat.com/SleepyShockingGelding-mobile.mp4)

Answer (score 0):

just create Some js script which will state that when it will find certain element will change color as determined previously. Use document.get element by id then if and else statement. A short example..

```html
<input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#000'; this.style.color = '#FFF';" />
```